# how to treat the dynamic json string as literal in rust

Tags: rust

I am using this rust code block to handle the json:

```
fn main() {
    let new_tags: String = "[{"code":"DEVELOPER"}]";
}
```

the compiler shows error `invalid suffix code`.how to treated the json to literal for dynamic content? I already know to convert static string as literal string like this:

```
    let new_tags: &str = r#"[{"code":"DEVELOPER"}]"#;
```

this is the debugging info when I am passed json in production code:

[image]

could not parse the right json string, the parsed return is Null.

Comment: I have changed my question to the right way.@ChayimFriedman

Comment: That's exactly what you do, `r#"[{"code":"DEVELOPER"}]"#` is a valid literal.

Comment: but it would not work when the json is dynamic in production code. @ChayimFriedman

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? When is the string going to change, and how?

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing yourself with respect to the meaning of escaped strings. In your original code (ignore the unrelated type error)

```rust
let new_tags: String = "[{"code":"DEVELOPER"}]";
```

the compiler has to bail because the `"` *inside* the string (`"code"`) stops the parser; what the parser sees is `"[{"`, `code` `":"` `DEVELOPER` `"}]"`, which makes no sense at all to the compiler. You could escape the inner `"`, as in `"[{\"code\":\"DEVELOPER\"}]"` or use a raw string (like you did) as in

```rust
let new_tags: &str = r#"[{"code":"DEVELOPER"}]"#;
```

which causes the parser to see the whole string as one literal (from `#"` all the way to `"#`).

But then you confuse yourself again in the line

```rust
let tag_str = format!("{}{}{}", "r#\"",new_tags, "\"#");
```

There is no need to put a literal `r#"` *into* the final string; the `r#"`/`"#` is only there to disaggregate the actual string (which contains `"`) from the way the string has to be written down in Rust code (which also uses `"`).

The JSON parser in `serde_json` will see the string `r#"[{"code":"DEVELOPER"}]"#`, which is obviously not valid JSON. `serde_json` would report the error, but in the line

```rust
serde_json::from_str(&*tag_str).unwrap_or_default();
```

you are supressing the error via the `unwrap_or_default` call, which gives you an `Value::Null`.

What you need to do is get rid of the `format!`-thing. The `r#"[{"code":"DEVELOPER"}]"#` is already valid JSON.